# next-router and redux is not fetching the previous state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, next.js

I have this component called announce:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import Layout from "../components/layout";
import { GetCategories } from "../redux/actions/category.action";
import { GetBrands } from "../redux/actions/brand.action";
import { GetEquipments } from "../redux/actions/equipment.action";
import { AddProduct } from "../redux/actions/product.action";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import AutoFormStepper from "../components/AutoFormStepper";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const Announce = ({
  categories,
  brands,
  equipments,
  GetBrands,
  GetCategories,
  GetEquipments,
  AddProduct
}) => {
  // Render data...

  useEffect(() => {
    GetCategories();
    GetBrands();
    GetEquipments();
  }, []);
  return (
    <Layout>
      <AutoFormStepper
        categories={categories}
        brands={brands}
        equipments={equipments}
        AddProduct={AddProduct}
      />
    </Layout>
  );
};

Announce.propTypes = {
  categories: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  brands: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  equipments: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  AddProduct: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    categories: state.categories,
    brands: state.brands,
    equipments: state.equipments,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  GetCategories,
  GetBrands,
  GetEquipments,
  AddProduct
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Announce);
```

The issue here is when I am located into this Page component , I've got a fetching of brands,categories..etc , but if create a Route.push("/usedCar") which is this component:

```
import React from "react";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Layout from "../components/layout";
import CardList from "../components/CardList";
import FilterDetail from "../components/FilterDetail";
import { GetProductsByFeatured } from "../redux/actions/product.action";
import { wrapper } from "../redux/store";

const UsedCar = ({ products }) => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Typography variant="h5" gutterBottom>
        Autos Destacados
      </Typography>
      <CardList products={products} />
      <FilterDetail />
    </Layout>
  );
};

export const getServerSideProps = wrapper.getServerSideProps(
  async ({ store }) => {
    await store.dispatch(GetProductsByFeatured());
    const products = await store.getState().products.docs;
    return {
      props: {
        products,
      },
    };
  }
);

export default UsedCar;
```

So, when the Route.push("/usedCar") does it is function, my prev state of categories, brands .. etc does exist into my current state. I do not have idea how to solve this.

[image]

[image]

Also I would like to mention that if using client useEffect to get the products it works.
so the problem I think is related with the getServerSideProps

Thanks.

Comment: I think that the problem is that a page with `getServerSideProps` will always be [rendered on the server side](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#only-runs-on-server-side), where the client state doesn't exist. So you'd need to fetch the other data as well in `getServerSideProps`.

Comment: yes, but I was expecting get the alert state :( within usedCar page

Comment: Try using [`getInitialProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps) instead. During a client-side transition, it'll run on the client (=your redux state will exist), but during a direct page load, it'll run on the server.

Comment: I just realize in the reducer  the HYDRATE method i can pass the state, so I want to mention I am using next-redux-wrapper